# The Graph view in Cutter is empty

Tags: radare2

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64525583/4999991), I'm trying to figure out how `cscript.exe` parses the `.wsh` Windows Script Host control files. First I [tried WinDbg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64561883/4999991), but Radare2-Cutter seems like a much nicer software TBH. What I did:

1. Opened the `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.exe`
2. Imported the previously downloaded official Microsoft symbols `File > Import PDB > cscript.pdb`
3. `View > Refresh Contents`

However, the Graph tab shows empty:

> Graph (Empty) 
>  No function detected. Cannot display graph.

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it.

**P.S.** Any other help towards solving the original problem is also highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please change the title and/or edit the question so the answer matches it? Maybe you can copy the Cutter part into a new one.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

debugging using cdb (windbg console)
open a elevated command prompt
run
`cdb -c "bp cscript!CscriptFile::create;g;kc;r;du@rcx;" cscript hell.vbs`

this sets a break point on create and dumps the stack when bp is hit

you can see cscript!CscriptEngine::Compile function parsing and compiling the file after this

```
Breakpoint 0 hit
Call Site
cscript!CScriptFile::Create
cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript
cscript!CHost::Execute
cscript!CHost::Main
cscript!main
cscript!_mainCRTStartup
cscript!mainCRTStartup
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart
rax=0000000000000000 rbx=000000e91cdff380 rcx=000002404a919a58
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=000000e91cdff600 rdi=000002404c6109a8
rip=00007ff617175b14 rsp=000000e91cdfeb58 rbp=0000000000000000
 r8=000000e91cdff600  r9=0000000000000000 r10=000002404a8fb2f0
r11=000000e91cdfeb60 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=000000e91cdff6c8
iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
cscript!CScriptFile::Create:
00007ff6`17175b14 48895c2410      mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbx ss:000000e9`1cdfeb68=0000000000000000
00000240`4a919a58  "c:\hell.vbs"
```

the function which Creates ,Loads ,Compiles And Executes the Script

```
0:000> uf /c cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript
cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript (00007ff6`17171d88)
  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0x39 (00007ff6`17171dc1):
    call to cscript!CScriptFile::Create (00007ff6`17175b14)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0x4c (00007ff6`17171dd4):
    call to cscript!CScriptFile::Load (00007ff6`17171cd0)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0x74 (00007ff6`17171dfc):
    call to cscript!CScriptingEngine::Compile (00007ff6`1717589c)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0x96 (00007ff6`17171e1e):
    call to ntdll!LdrpDispatchUserCallTarget (00007ffd`f574c510)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0xc3 (00007ff6`17171e4b):
    call to ntdll!LdrpDispatchUserCallTarget (00007ffd`f574c510)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0xd5 (00007ff6`17171e5d):
    call to cscript!CTimer::Stop (00007ff6`17174478)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0x614f (00007ff6`17177ed7):
    call to cscript!CHost::ReportLoadError (00007ff6`1717b930)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0x6165 (00007ff6`17177eed):
    call to cscript!CTimer::Start (00007ff6`1717d3dc)

  cscript!CHost::RunStandardScript+0x6183 (00007ff6`17177f0b):
    call to ntdll!LdrpDispatchUserCallTarget (00007ffd`f574c510)

0:000>
```

Comment: while useful, this does not provide an answer to the question of missing functions in Cutter

Comment: Answer is for the foot note requesting solution for original problem